# window.close no funciona con streetview

Tags: javascript, html

estoy intentando abrir una ventana flotante de street view y después cerrarla. Si abro una ventana de google.com, la puedo cerrar. Pero, con la de street view, tras abrirla, no puedo cerrarla.
Si la abro y cierro al instante si se cierra. Entiendo que street view redirecciona la página a otra y por eso no se puede cerrar una vez abierta. ¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Lo he probado en https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default_default

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Google</h1>

<button onclick="openGoogle()">Open "google"</button>
<button onclick="closeGoogle()">Close "google"</button>
<br>
<h1>StreetView</h1>
<button onclick="openStreetView()">Open "streetview"</button>
<button onclick="closeStreetView()">Close "streetview"</button>

<script>
let google;
let streetview;

function openGoogle() {
  google = window.open("https://www.google.com/", "Google", "width=800,height=800");
}

function closeGoogle() {
  google.close();
}


function openStreetView() {
  streetview = window.open("https://www.google.com/maps/@43.3396007,-1.8096601,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sZ81gym2y_KL-MPWdBQ1Mqg!2e0!7i16384!8i8192", "Google", "width=800,height=800");
}

function closeStreetView() {
  streetview.close();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```